# Vue - submitting dynamically created form

Tags: javascript, forms, vuejs2

I am creating a form dynamically with the data that I get from the backend:

```
{
    "title": "Contact Me",
    "fields": [
        {
            "label": "Name",
            "type": "textbox",
            "required": "1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Email",
            "type": "email",
            "required": "1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Message",
            "type": "textarea",
            "required": "1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Submit",
            "type": "submit",
            "required": null
        }
    ]
}
```

In Vue the component where I am making this form looks like this:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit()" class="form">
  <template v-for="input in ninjaForm.fields">
    <div v-if="input.type != 'submit' && input.type != 'textarea'" class="control">
      <input
        v-bind:value="form[input.label]"
        class="input is-large"
        :type="input.type"
        :name="input.label.toLowerCase()"
        :required="input.required == 1">
      <label>{{ input.label }}</label>
    </div>
    <div v-if="input.type == 'textarea'" class="control">
      <textarea
        v-bind:value="form[input.label]"
        class="textarea"
        :name="input.label.toLowerCase()">
      </textarea>
      <label>{{ input.label }}</label>
    </div>
    <div v-if="input.type == 'submit'">
      <button class="button is-primary">{{ input.label }}</button>
    </div>
  </template>
</form>
```

I would like to submit this data back to the backend, but I am not sure how to do that, I have tried with something like this:

```
data() {
      return {
        form: {},
      };
    },
    methods: {
      submit() {
        let payload = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          params: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.form))
        };
console.log(payload);
        this.$backend.post('submit', null, payload)
            .then(_ => {
              this.response = 'Meldingen ble sendt!';
            }, err => {
              console.warn(err);
              this.response = 'En feil oppstod under innsending av skjemaet, prøv igjen senere.';
            });

      }
    }
```

But when I am doing `console.log(this.form)` I get an `observer object`, and if I do `console.log(payload)` I get an empty `params` property. What am I doing wrong and how should I fix this so that I can send form data as a params object?

I have tried with setting the form properties on created method, like this:

```
created() {
      this.ninjaForm.fields.forEach(field => this.form[field.label.toLowerCase()] = '');
    },
```

Which has made an object with properties that looks like this:

```
form: {
  email:"",
  message:"",
  name:"",
  submit:""
 }
```

But, when I was submitting the form, the values of this properties where still empty:

```
v-bind:value="form[input.label.toLowerCase()]"
```

I have also tried with changing `v-bind:value` to `v-model`, but then I have got an error:

> v-model does not support dynamic input types. Use v-if branches
>   instead.

Comment: Maybe use the created hook to populate the form object in data() with the backend data and then bind the values to the same object? Then you can post the form object back again on submit.

Comment: I have tried by doing that but then I get: v-model does not support dynamic input types

Answer (score 1):

Please check this thread:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3915#issuecomment-294707727

Seems like it works with v-model. However, this doesn't work when you use a v-bind on the input type. The only workaround is to create a v-if for every possible form type. Really annoying, but there seems to be no apparent other solution.